# Increasing efficiency of table intersect

Tags: r, intersect

I have 2 tables.They are both in the in the form  chromosome, start and end coordinates on this chromosome. The first table contains genes and the second table contains short sequences which may or may not fall in these genes. In my real dataset, genes is about 50.000 rows and sequences is about 7.000.000 rows and both tables have various extra columns. I would like to find overlaps between the two tables.

```
chromosome=as.character(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5), each=10000))
start=floor(runif(50000, min=0, max=50000000))
end=start+floor(runif(10000, min=0, max=10000))
genes=cbind(chromosome, start, end)

startseq=floor(runif(7000000, min=0, max=50000000))
endseq=startseq+4
sequences=cbind(chromosome, startseq, endseq)
```

I am trying to find all intersects using:

```
for (g in 1:nrow(sequences)) {
  seqrow=as.vector(sequences[g,])  
  rownr=which(genes[,1]==seqrow[1] & genes[,2] < seqrow[2] & genes[,3] > seqrow[3])
  print(rownr)
}
```

I intend to use these row numbers to perform actions on the extra columns I have in my real dataset. The problem for now is that the described process is rather slow. In which ways could I speed up this intersect?

Comment: Seems like @emilliman5 code solves your problem, but I still want to comment one thing. When you create these tables, `genes` and `sequences`, you use `cbind` function. And since all the inputs are atomic vectors, and one of them is a character vector (`chromosome`), it creates a character matrix. Type `head(chromosome)` - all the numbers actually became strings - and I think that's not an appropriate thing, when you want to compare numbers later. What you need in such cases is to create a `data.frame` here instead of `matrix`: `data.frame(sequences, start, end)`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make use of [bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org) for this task, and specifically the [GenomicRanges](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html) package. This will return an object of class "Hits" which will contain the indices of the overlaps. You could also use the `intersect` function but this returns the interval of the intersect not the id of the intersecting seq. In short bioconductor and GenomicRanges has many useful set functions that are quite fast.

```
## try http:// if https:// URLs are not supported
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite()
biocLite("GenomicRanges") ## I think genomicranges is part of the standard bioconductor install but if not this will install it.


library(GenomicRanges)

set.seed(8675309)
chromosome <- as.character(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5), each=10000))
start <- floor(runif(50000, min=0, max=50000000))
end <- start+floor(runif(10000, min=0, max=10000))
genes <- cbind(chromosome, start, end)

startseq <- floor(runif(7000000, min=0, max=50000000))
endseq <- startseq+4
chromosome <- sample(c(1,2,3,4,5), size = 7000000, replace=T)
sequences=cbind(chromosome, startseq, endseq)

genes <- GRanges(seqnames = chromosome, ranges = IRanges(start = start, end = end))
seqs <- GRanges(seqnames = chromosome, ranges = IRanges(start = startseq, end = endseq))

x <- findOverlaps(seqs, genes)
head(x)

#Hits object with 6 hits and 0 metadata columns:
#      queryHits subjectHits
#      <integer>   <integer>
#  [1]         2       41673
#  [2]         2       47476
#  [3]         3       20048
#  [4]         4        9624
#  [5]         4        5662
#  [6]         4        1531
#  -------
#  queryLength: 7000000
#  subjectLength: 50000
```

Comment: No more time to investigate it today, but it looks promising. Will look at it tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: It works perfectly and very fast. One more question, is it possible to just have it output as a normally subsettable matrix which I can iterate over?